# control order that routes are matched when using a custom directive/action

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a catchall route that is catching my request before my call to add_route within an action created with a custom directive.  How can I prevent that from happening?  Ie. manually place the catchall route at the end of the route matching process or put my action's add_route at the front of the route matching process?

I tried swapping the order of the `includes` between `admin/routes.py` and `routes.py` but that didn't seem to have an affect.  A quick solution (and probably good idea thinking about it now) is to filter admin from the pattern in the catchall.  But I feel like this is going to come up again where I cannot do that so I'm asking this question.

### `__init__.py`

```py
def main(global_config, **settings):
    #...
    config.include('.directives')
    #...
    config.include(".routes")
    #...
    for k in (".customer", ".admin"):
        config.scan(k) # this picks up the admin/admin_routes.py

    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

### `admin/routes.py`

```py
def includeme(config):
    config.add_dispatched_route(
        "admin-plants-edit",
        "/admin/plants/{id}",
        'plant',
    )
```

### `routes.py`

```py
def includeme(config):
    #...
    config.add_route("page-view", "/*url")
```

### `directives.py`

```py
from pyramid.config import PHASE0_CONFIG
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPNotFound

def includeme(config):
    def add_dispatched_route(config, route_name, route_pattern, dispatch_with):
        def route_factory(request):
            api = request.find_service(name=dispatch_with)
            obj = api.by_id(request.matchdict["id"])
            if not obj:
                raise HTTPNotFound()
            return obj
        def route_pregenerator(request, elements, kw):
            api = request.find_service(name=dispatch_with)
            try:
                obj = kw.pop(api.get_pregenerator_kw())
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                kw["id"] = obj.id
            return elements, kw
        def register():
            config.add_route(route_name, route_pattern, factory=route_factory, pregenerator=route_pregenerator)
        config.action(('dispatched_route', route_name), register, order=PHASE0_CONFIG)

    config.add_directive('add_dispatched_route', add_dispatched_route)
```

Comment: The catchall route should be the last one declared. Try moving it after the block `for k in (".customer", ".admin"):` You might need to break up `routes.py` into two files, one with all but catchall at the start and the other with `catchall.py` at the end.

Comment: @StevePiercy I like the idea of the explicit catchall file so I tried that and it doesn't seem to work.  It seems that the action registers the add_route after all the other add_route calls occur even though the call to the directive occurs before the inclusion of the catchall file.  This is sort of an edge case because a catchall is pretty rare.  I can't control the order of the actions because I essentially call out the another action with the call to add_route.  I'm going to just implement a non-framework solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the phases work in Pyramid doesn't allow you to re-order actions within a phase. Basically imagine that every call to `config.add_route` gets appended to a list, and then later that list is iterated in order to add the routes. You cannot inject a call to `config.add_route` before another call to it.

However if you wrap every call to add_route in your own action, then you have an opportunity to defer everything, order things, and then call `config.add_route` with each route in the order you wish.

Comment: I ended up just wrapping everything in my own add_route like you suggested and that worked.